# Search highlight html not rendered when using advanced search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I'm using daily a saved search for posts created yesterday with score >3 in java.
If I'm using the `java` tag only, it shows the search highlight fine:
[image]

---

But when I'm using my link (which is using advanced search), the tag info is showed in raw html:
[image]

This is the search link you can use for reproduce the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+is%3Aquestion+created%3A1d+score%3A3

I've also tried in incognito mode.
I'm using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) , Windows 7 x64

Comment: <span class="duplicated-this-is-bad">Duplicated.  This is bad.</span>

Comment: Meta.SE cross-site post: [Unparsed HTML shows on search result page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322139/289905)

Comment: I guess [meta.se] is dead now, considering the number of views :)

Comment: I noticed the same issue (using Firefox 61.0.1 on Ubuntu); as of now, the issue is still present for me.

Comment: I think that [meta.se] would be the only meta where you can bounty a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed by removing these highlights from tag excerpts altogether. Details: [Unparsed HTML shows on search result page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322139/unparsed-html-shows-on-search-result-page/323262#323262)

Comment: I confirm that is fixed now, thanks !