# Escaped HTML in tag warnings

Tags: bug, tags

The HTML in tag warnings suddenly gets escaped.

**Small repro:**

1. Click ask a question on SO.
2. Add the [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) or [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag.
3. Click the body.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Side question: should the warning remain after removing the tag?

Comment: Ah! Yes, you are right! I barely noticed it, real web developers automatically render this in their visual cortex. But this explains why the links didn't work, thank you!

Comment: Also happens with all the notices (e.g. add the regex tag), warnings about URL shorteners, e.g. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825267) answer. Something is completely broken.

Comment: Interesting to see that the tags are ms-word, ms-access, excel, powerpoint, visio. Understandably, "word" and "access" are generic words, but it would be nice to always have "ms-" for consistency.

Comment: didn't we have a [similar issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378836/search-highlight-html-not-rendered-when-using-advanced-search) not too long ago?

Comment: No repro Firefox 60.8.0esr (64-bit), Debian build.

Comment: Guess this is [meta-tag:status-completed] without notifying us. Can no longer reproduce as well.